# Les lettres accentuées de la langue française

Tags: orthographe, histoire, alphabet

- À quand remonte l'utilisation de la première lettre accentuée du français?
- Est-ce que la motivation première a été la nécessité de représenter la prononciation?
- Quel a été le premier accent?

Comment: Vous trouverez un article que je trouve très bien fait ici : http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article104

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outre les 26 lettres de l’alphabet, l’écriture standard du français emploie cinq signes diacritiques (accents aigu, grave et circonflexe, tréma et cédille) et les deux ligatures <æ> et <œ>. S’ajoutent ainsi 16 lettres : é, è, ê, ë, à, â, î, ï, ô, ù, û, ü, ÿ, æ, œ et ç.

Les accents aigu, grave et circonflexe et le tréma ont été empruntés au grec, la cédille à l’espagnol. Les ligatures <æ> et <œ> ont leur origine dans l’écriture médiévale du latin.

Ces trois accents sont apparus progressivement dans la langue, quand les caractères du latin ont semblé insuffisants pour rendre compte à l’écrit de la diversité des sons du français. Les éditeurs-imprimeurs de la Renaissance décident alors d’utiliser des lettres « diacritiques », c’est-à-dire qui modifient la prononciation de la voyelle qui les précède.

À partir du XVIe siècle, pour apporter des précisions phonétiques, des signes sont ajoutés au-dessus des lettres d’un mot : c’est une véritable innovation par rapport au latin, qui ne comporte pas d’accent. Le premier à voir le jour est l’accent aigu, confiné d’abord à la toute fin des mots. Peu à peu l’usage du grave et du circonflexe se répand.

Pour aller plus loin (et les sources pour cette petite réponse)

http://j.poitou.free.fr/pro/html/ltn/diacritiques.html

https://www.francealumni.fr/fr/statique/petite-histoire-des-accents-du-francais-11335

**EDIT** (voir commentaire)

À noter que les accents grecs sont tardifs (période hellénistique et surtout byzantine), le tréma ne date même que du Moyen Âge, juste avant la Renaissance.

Comment: À noter que les accents grecs sont tardifs (période hellénistique et surtout byzantine), le tréma ne date même que du Moyen Âge, juste avant la Renaissance.